# Closing Streams passed to MultipartFormDataOutput

Tags: java, stream, resteasy

Resteasy [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.0.Final/userguide/html/Multipart.html) does not explain who is responsible for closing streams passed to `MultipartFormDataOutput`. Let's consider the following example:

```
WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("url");
MultipartFormDataOutput formData = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/image1"));
FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/image2"));
formData.addFormData("image", fis1, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
formData.addFormData("image", fis2, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
Entity<MultipartFormDataOutput> entity = Entity.entity(formData, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
Response response = target.request().post(entity);
```

Will the `fis1` and `fis2` be closed by the resteasy or the user should take care of closing these streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can answer my question myself, hope someone will benefit from this.

Resteasy will close the passed stream. In my case, the `InputStreamProvider` will take care of closing the `FileInputStream`.

```
     public void writeTo(InputStream inputStream, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException
   {
           LogMessages.LOGGER.debugf("Provider : %s,  Method : writeTo", getClass().getName());
       try
       {
           int c = inputStream.read();
           if (c == -1)
           {
               httpHeaders.putSingle(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, Integer.toString(0));
               entityStream.write(new byte[0]); // fix RESTEASY-204
               return;
           }
           else
               entityStream.write(c);
         ProviderHelper.writeTo(inputStream, entityStream);
       }
       finally
       {
         inputStream.close();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to be sure that they will be closed.

```
WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("url");
MultipartFormDataOutput formData = new MultipartFormDataOutput();

try(FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/image1")));
    FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/image2")))
{
  formData.addFormData("image", fis1, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
  formData.addFormData("image", fis2, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
  Entity<MultipartFormDataOutput> entity = Entity.entity(formData, 
  MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
  Response response = target.request().post(entity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but not really answering my question.